# rsync synching unchanged files

Tags: backup, samba, rsync

New to rsync here.
I used it to backup files on an external drive on my home drives. 
My rsync line is :

```
sudo rsync -vv -rP /inputFolder ~/backupFolder
```

I did 2 backups back to back to verify if rsync backed up only files that had been modified, as I understood from what I had read. But to my surprise, the second backup took as much time as the first one, even though no files had changed between both backups.

Important note: the backup is on a samba network drive.

Shouldn't the second backup been much faster since no file had changed since the first one?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to include the `-t` command line argument to `rsync`, telling it to preserve the time stamps, as otherwise the time stamps are bound to differ, causing files to be transferred anew. Alternatively, you should include `-I` to tell `rsync` to ignore time stamps. Anyway, you might enjoy some quality time with

```
man rsync
```

Comment: -1..considering you are referring timestamp to mod time by as you have used `-t``the time stamps are bound to differ` - why is that?

Comment: Yes, the time stamp is the mod time of the file. rsync-ing from one place to another is of course a file copy, and the destination file (although named the same) will then gain its on mod time, unless rsync is told (by -t) to "correct" it to be the same as the mod time of the source file.

Comment: My bad..downvote removed..i was rolling back my edit and saw this and missed the initial case..

Answer (score 0):

By default, `rsync` checks file size and modification time before transferring to check whether the files are identical or not.

The `rsync` transfer time is rather misleading for files of same size and modification time, if you do `rsync -vvv` then you would see `rsync` spends most of the time doing the delta transfer check to make sure the files are identical, `rsync` does this chunk by chunk. In a nutshell, if the size and modification time remains the same, `rsync` won't do a transfer.

Also note that you can do a checksum before transfer by using the `--checksum` option.

In your case though, as the file sizes are same then it must be the modification time causing the files to be re-transferred. This is justified as you have used no option that preserves modification time on `rsync`.

You can use -t (`--times`) option to preserve modification time or -a (`--archive`) option that includes `-rlptgoD` options together:

```
sudo rsync -vv -trP /inputFolder ~/backupFolder

sudo rsync -avvP /inputFolder ~/backupFolder
```

Comment: The commands I use are : `rsync -vv -trOP folderA folderB;   rsync -vv -trOP folderB folderC`

Comment: Somehow A->B works fine (no synching when no changes) but B->C ALWAYS syncs, even when no change to any file has been made.  1 detail that might come to play here : C is on a samba drive and all drives are NTFS.